# boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket doesn't read anything

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp, boost-asio

This is actually my first program in socket programming other than copy-pasting the tutorial code and having fun. Anyway it does not work. I think I have carefully read the documentation but maybe it wasn't enough. I'm suspecting my use of `socket::read_some()` in `read_message()` since my problematic program stops at the reading part. I thought the way I used it should be okay because the documentation of `socket::read_some()` stated that "the function call will block until one or more bytes of data has been read successfully, or until an error occurs." Below is my code. Any help appreciated.

```
void read_message(std::string& message, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket)
{
    std::stringstream message_stream;
    while (true)
    {
        std::array<char, 128> buffer;
        boost::system::error_code error;
        size_t len = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), error);
        if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
        {
            break;
        }
        message_stream.write(buffer.data(), len);
    }
    message = message_stream.str();
}
```

**server.cpp**

```
int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 9999));
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
        acceptor.accept(socket);
        std::cout << "connected with client, waiting for a message\n";
        std::string message;
        read_message(message, socket);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = socket.remote_endpoint();
        std::cout << "message received from " << endpoint.address().to_string() <<
            ':' << endpoint.port() << '\n' << message << '\n';
        boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(message));
        if (message.compare("quit") == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**client.cpp**

```
int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "your message to be sent: ";
        std::string message;
        std::getline(std::cin, message);
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("localhost", "9999");
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
        boost::asio::connect(socket, endpoint_iterator);
        std::cout << "connected to server\n";
        boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(message));
        read_message(message, socket);
        std::cout << "message received from server: " << message << '\n';
        if (message.compare("quit") == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `read_message` function: you read until `eof`, but you'll get `eof` only when the socket gets closed.

Perhaps you meant to return from `read_message` when some delimiter is encountered, eg. '\n'? Then you can either inspect the buffer manually, or use [`read_until`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read_until.html) function.

Using `read_until` function, `read_message` would look like this:

```
void read_message(std::string& message, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket)
{
  std::stringstream message_stream;
  boost::asio::streambuf buffer;
  boost::system::error_code error;
  size_t len = read_until(socket, buffer, '\n', error);
  if (len)
  {
    message_stream.write(boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char *>(buffer.data()), len);
    message = message_stream.str();
  }
}
```

Remember to append '\n' to the message you send from the client:

```
//...
std::cout << "connected to server\n";
boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(message + '\n'));
read_message(message, socket);
//...
```

Comment: That's kind of parsing the output, can you please share a way in which we can extract the statusCode, message and the content? Given that the header size remains constant but the content size may vary.