# Socket cannot receive data? Client is written using Boost.asyio library. Server is written in python

Tags: python, c++, sockets, boost

**client code**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::asio;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    io_service service;
    ip::tcp::endpoint ep(ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 2001);

    ip::tcp::socket sock(service);
    sock.connect(ep);

    boost::asio::streambuf sb;
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    size_t len;
    while (true)
    {
        //write data
        sock.write_some(buffer("ok", 2));
        //read data
        read(sock, sb, transfer_all(),ec);
        //handle error
        if (ec && ec != error::eof) {
            std::cout << "receive failed: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            const char* data = buffer_cast<const char*>(sb.data());
            std::cout << data << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**server code**

```
import socket
import threading

s = socket.socket()
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
s.bind(("127.0.0.1",2001))

s.listen(5)
cons = []

print "begin....."
while True:
    con,addr = s.accept()
    #cons.append(con)
    print con
    while True:
        data = con.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            con.close()
            break;
        print data
        con.send("123")
s.close()
```

Client can send "ok" to the server, but it cannot receive "123" from the server.

If I use a client written in python, the server and client can communicate well.

Could someone tell the reason about this mistake?

Comment: The read function reads until EOL, this only happens if your TCP connection gets closed. If you terminate the server you will notice that the client will instantly read the data and also close the socket.

Comment: @R.Joiny Do you know how to limit the maximum buffer size? I want read 1024k data every time.

Comment: with the tcp socket method `read_some` you can set the buffer size by limiting the `boost::asio::buffer` like you did with the ok: `buffer("ok", 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `tcp::socket::read_some` method. This method blocks until something gets received to the socket and then reads the data (while the read(...) function reads the whole file/socket until EOF, which only occurs if the connection drops)

[You can read up the usage here.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/read_some/overload2.html)

**Example:**

```
std::string recbuf;
while (true)
{
    //write data
    sock.write_some(buffer("ok", 2));
    //read data
    sock.read_some(buffer(recbuf, 1024), ec);
    //handle error
    if (ec && ec != error::eof) {
        std::cout << "receive failed: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << recbuf << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found similar question [boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket doesn't read anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957299/boostasioiptcpsocket-doesnt-read-anything).

Using ***read_until*** can solve this question.